# Combine mp4 video and a RTMP stream into 1 RTMP output stream via ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, rtmp

I need a ffmpeg command to first feed a mp4 video into a RTMP output stream, then followed by a RTMP input subsequently; what should be the parameters to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ffmpeg
-i intro.mp4
-i rtmp://second-input-server:port/input-id
-filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[merged_video][merged_audio]"
-map [merged_video] -map [merged_audio] -f flv rtmp://final-output:port/merged
```

- We are taking two inputs, one from a local file (`intro.mp4`) and one using an rtmp address (`rtmp://second-input-server:port/input-id`).
- We are using the `concat` filter here, specifying that it has 2 segments to concant (`n=2`), each segment having 1 video (`v=1`) and 1 audio stream (`a=1`).
- We are labelling the concatted streams as `merged_video` and `merged_audio`, and muxing them into `flv` format, before sending that to the output rtmp server (`rtmp://final-output:port/merged`).

This assumes that you have the two inputs having same number of streams (1 video and 1 audio), same frame rate, same dimensions etc. If you don't, you may need to add additional filters (e.g. `scale`, `fps`) and stream selectors (e.g. `[0:v:0]`, `[1:a:1]`) above to first make the two streams have the same characteristics, before feeding those to the `concat` filter.